# url with AND giving 403 Forbidden error in nginx

Tags: django, url, nginx

my nginx setting is as follow:

```
    server {
    listen      80;
    server_name 172.16.0.150 ;
    charset     utf-8;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project.error.log info;

    client_max_body_size 1600M;

    location / {
        root /var/www/project_200;
        try_files $uri @wsgiapp;
    }

    location @wsgiapp {
        uwsgi_read_timeout 10800;

        uwsgi_pass  unix:///tmp/project.sock;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /geoserver/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://172.16.0.160:8080/geoserver/;
    }
}
```

when I hit the following request to the browser, it gives me **403 Forbidden** error as below:

## request:

*http://172.16.0.150/geoserver/wfs/?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeName=geonode:new_lccs&startIndex=0&count=10&maxFeatures=10&sortBy=&version=1.0.0&outputFormat=json&exceptions=application/json&CQL_FILTER=LCCS_code%20IN%20(%27BH%27%2C%20%27BNl%27%2C%20%27Ba%27)%20AND%20BBOX(the_geom,80.57373046874999,17.560246503294877,103.271484375,30.675715404167747)*

## response

[image]

I came to figure out that, **AND** in my url is the problem for nginx. but could not get any solution.